# Passing a complex model to controller using AJAX in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to pass the model from the view to controller using AJAX, the AJAX call works with a hard-coded JSON string but fails with the actual JSON and I don't know why, any help is very appreciated. Step by step this is what I did:

**In the view I have**

```
  <script>
    var FeedData = @Html.Raw(Json.Serialize(Model));
</script>
```

**In My JavaScript file**

```
    var index= $(this).val();

    var test = window.FeedData[index];

    var json = {
        prop1: 'test',
        prop2: 'test2',
    };

    var data = {
        json: JSON.stringify(json)
    };

    var data2 = {
        json: JSON.stringify(test)
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "/Feed/GetFeedDetails",
        data: data,
        success: function (json) {
            if (json) {
                alert('ok');
            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }
        },
    });
```

Ok, Both `data` and `data2` variables are JSON stringified..

`data: data,` // Works

`data: data2,`//this does not work

**My Controller**

```
public async Task<PartialViewResult> GetFeedDetails(string json)
    {
         Feed feedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Feed>(json);
        return PartialView("FeedDetailsModal", feedData );
    }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `window.FeedData[value]`?

Comment: window.FeedData is IEnumerable<Feed> and value is index ( I edited my code so it's more understandable)..
Therefore window.FeedData[value] is a Feed model

Comment: FeedData should not use JSon.Serialize but JSonEncode. I also suggest to use a function to assign this value to your JS var, like `var feedData = fromModel(@JsonEncode(Model)); function fromModel(model) { return model; }`

Comment: Hi @AsımGündüz, any updates about this case?

Answer (score 0):

> the AJAX call works with a hard-coded JSON string but fails with the actual JSON and I don't know why

In your code, we can find that you set Ajax request method to `'GET'`, so the data would be passed through query string, if you can not get expected data in action method, please use browser developer tools Network tool to capture request and check if well-formatted data is passed.

Besides, your action method accepts string-type parameter and manually convert to a `Feed` object, to achieve same, you can try to make action method accept `Feed` type parameter and make it automatically bind value to properties of model class via model binding feature.

```
public IActionResult GetFeedDetails([FromBody]Feed feed)
{
    //...
```

Pass complex data through request body instead of in query string, like below.

```
var data2 = window.FeedData[index];


$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    url: "/Feed/GetFeedDetails",
    data: JSON.stringify(data2),
    success: function (json) {
        if (json) {
            alert('ok');
        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }
    },
});
```

Test Result

[image]